# Phpspreadsheet excel parsing throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am using phpspreadsheet for parsing an excel file. I have `5` sheets and `5000` records in each. Total `25000` records in the excel file. I am getting memory limit error, 500 internal error. Is this expected or am I doing wrong? Please find my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    ini_set("memory_limit",-1);

    $logger = new Logger();
    $startTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $logger->log('Import start time: '  . $startTime);
    $client = new Redis();
    $client->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
    $pool = new RedisCachePool($client);
    $simpleCache = new SimpleCacheBridge($pool);
    $options = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE;
    Settings::setCache($simpleCache);
    Settings::setLibXmlLoaderOptions($options);
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    $worksheetNames = $reader->listWorksheetNames($fileName);
    $chunkSize = 20;
    $totalRow = 6000;
    foreach ($worksheetNames as $worksheetName) {
        $emptyRowCount = 0;
        if (in_array($worksheetName, self::SHEET_BLACKLIST)) {
            continue;
        }
        $logger->log('Processing the Sheet: '  . $worksheetName);
        for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= $totalRow; $startRow += $chunkSize) {

            if ($emptyRowCount >= 10) {
                $logger->log('Found continuos empty cells. Skipping to next sheet');
                continue 2;
            }
            $chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilter($startRow, $chunkSize);
            $reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
            $reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($worksheetName);
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($fileName);
            $objWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $chunkSize = 20;
            $logger->log('Import Started');
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

                $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
                $logger->log(' RowIndex: '  . $rowIndex);
                if (in_array($rowIndex, self::ROW_BLACKLIST)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE);
                $res = [];
                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    $column = $cell->getColumn();
                    if (in_array($column, self::COLUMN_BLACKLIST)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $logger->log('Cordinate: '  .  $cell->getCoordinate());

                    $mergeRange = $cell->getMergeRange();

                    if ($cell->isInMergeRange()) {
                        $logger->log('In MERGE RANGE');

                        if ($cell->isMergeRangeValueCell()) {
                            $logger->log('it is a MergeRangeValueCell');
                            $logger->log('Value: '  .  $cell->getCalculatedValue());
                            $res[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                        } else {
                            $logger->log('it is not a MergeRangeValueCell');
                            $mergeRange = $cell->getMergeRange();
                            $logger->log('Merge range: ' . $mergeRange);
                            $mergeRange = Coordinate::splitRange($mergeRange);
                            $firstCellInRange = $mergeRange[0];
                            $val = $objWorksheet->getCell($firstCellInRange[0])->getCalculatedValue();
                            $logger->log('Value: '  .  $val);
                            $res[] = $val;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $logger->log('Value: '  .  $cell->getCalculatedValue());
                        $res[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                    }
                }

                if (array_filter($res)) {
                    $emptyRowCount = 0;
                    $rohreRepository = new RohreRepository();
                    $title = 'Rohre_' . $worksheetName . '_' . $i;
                    $logger->log('Title: '  .  $title);
                    $logger->log('Going to create : '  .  json_encode($res));
                    $rohreRepository->create($res, $title);
                } else {
                    $emptyRowCount++;
                    $logger->log('Empty row: Not creating a post');
                }

                $i++;
            }
        }
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($worksheetName);
        if ($sheet) {
            $sheetIndex = $spreadsheet->getIndex($sheet);
            $logger->log('Removing sheet. Sheet index: '  .  $sheetIndex);
            $spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex($sheetIndex);
        }
    }
    $endTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $logger->log('Import end time: '  . $endTime);

    $start = new DateTime($startTime);
    $totalTimeTaken = $start->diff(new DateTime($endTime));

    $minutes = $totalTimeTaken->days * 24 * 60;
    $minutes += $totalTimeTaken->h * 60;
    $minutes += $totalTimeTaken->i;
    $logger->log('Total time: '  . $minutes . 'Minutes');
```